# Reading a semicolon-separated file

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file that is separated by ";" from the following location - http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing

I have tried to use both read.csv(data,sep=";") and read.csv2(data,dec="."), but it has not worked and it reads the file as having 1 column.

What am I doing wrong and how could I get R to read this?

Thank you!

Comment: `read.csv(..., sep=';')` seems to work just fine on both `bank.csv` and `bank-full.csv `.

Comment: It will be easier to work out what has gone wrong if you update your question to include the exact code (and any other steps) that you used when you had the problem.

Comment: Hi, I first add to working directory and then try to read the file: setwd("~/Personal/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/project")     bankdata<-read.csv("bank.csv",header=T,sep=";")                                 The result is one column:   56;"housemaid";"married";"basic.4y";"no";"no";"no";"telephone";"may";"mon";261;1;999;0;"nonexistent";1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;"no"
2 57;"services";"married";"high.school";"unknown";"no";"no";"telephone";"may";"mon";149;1;999;0;"nonexistent";1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;"no"

Comment: https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/11-supp-read-write-csv/ , 5th in google on "csv semicolon [r]"

Answer (score 4):

One of the parameters to `read.csv()` must include the location of your .csv file. Only then can you save it into as a data frame called 'data'.  If you are using a MacBook:

```
data <- read.csv("User/Benjamin/Desktop/bank.csv", sep=";")
```

and if you're on Windows:

```
data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Benjamin\\Desktop\\bank.csv", sep=";")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use the '/' for separating paths on windows

Comment: I tried to do that but it gives me this error message:                                                                                              Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/project': Permission denied

Comment: @dplmkl Try switching the path filename to `C:\\Users\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\project\\bank.csv`. Using backslashes \ instead of the normal slash /.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what dataset you're trying to read. The following code downloads and unzips `banks-full` dataset from your URL, check this out:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/bank.zip",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "bank-full.csv")
unlink(temp)
bank.df <- read.table("bank-full.csv", sep=";", header=T)
str(bank.df)
# 'data.frame': 45211 obs. of  17 variables:
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters to read.csv() must include the location of your .csv file. Only then can you save it into as a data frame called 'data'.

```
Use getClass().getResource("put your file path here")
```

.

Comment: This is not R code, is it?